# Animating strike-through on a TextView

Tags: android, animation, textview, swipe, strikethrough

I have been searching a lot on how to animate the strike-through affect on a TextView to no results. Only thing I am getting on forums and StackOverflow is:

```
some_text_view.setPaintFlags(some_text_view.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
```

What I want to do is, animate the strike-through affect like in todo apps on Play Store e.g. Any.do has it on an item left-to-right swipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Extend TextView and make a custom view which checks if the STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG is set and fires off an animation that will draw a small line on the text incrementing it's width on each frame of the animation.
- Use an empty view and place it on your TextView (using RelativeLayout, FrameLayout etc). Make sure the dimensions of this view match exactly with your TextView. Then animate this view following the same strategy as before: Draw a horizontal line at the center of the view whose width is incremented at each frame of the animation.

If you want to know how to the animation itself, then you can look up [Animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html), [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) etc and their [related guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: I'd go with the first method, the second will not work on a multiple line text view unless you use a view for every single row of the text.

Comment: @npace good point. The second method should only be used for single line text.

Comment: yeah first method seems more scalable also. Btw any pointers on how to accomplish the animation part @AnupCowkur (referring to some code as a kick starter) ?

Comment: I don't have anything specific to your situation but this tutorial from Styling Android has a good guide to android animation: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/129

Comment: Also, animation should work with OS versions < 3.0 (Honeycomb)

Comment: If you plan to use the Honeycomb animation API on versions less than 3.0, then you can check out http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: Great. I'll look into it. Thanks for the help. Will mark the answer accepted, when I would have resolved the issue using your method :)

Answer (score 4):

```
private fun TextView.startStrikeThroughAnimation(): ValueAnimator {
val span = SpannableString(text)
val strikeSpan = StrikethroughSpan()
val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(text.length)
animator.addUpdateListener {
    span.setSpan(strikeSpan, 0, it.animatedValue as Int, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    text = span
    invalidate()
}
animator.start()
return animator
```

}

```
private fun TextView.reverseStrikeThroughAnimation(): ValueAnimator {
val span = SpannableString(text.toString())
val strikeSpan = StrikethroughSpan()
val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(text.length, 0)
animator.addUpdateListener {
    span.setSpan(strikeSpan, 0, it.animatedValue as Int, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    text = span
    invalidate()
}
animator.start()
return animator
```

}

Comment: I've implemented this approach and had issues with reverse strike after initially starting the strike on the same `textview`. Most likely because there is already a `strike span` set to the `textview`. Setting the `textview.text` before calling the reverse does the trick but may not be the best way

Comment: How can we increase the length of the strike through line?

Answer (score 3):

I used this approach to make strikethrough animation:

```
private void animateStrikeThrough1(final TextView tv) {
    final int ANIM_DURATION = 1000;              //duration of animation in millis
    final int length = tv.getText().length();
    new CountDownTimer(ANIM_DURATION, ANIM_DURATION/length) {
        Spannable span = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
        StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //calculate end position of strikethrough in textview
            int endPosition = (int) (((millisUntilFinished-ANIM_DURATION)*-1)/(ANIM_DURAT [ION/length));
            endPosition = endPosition > length ?
                    length : endPosition;
            span.setSpan(strikethroughSpan, 0, endPosition,
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            tv.setText(span);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate

Answer (score 0):

```
// Created by kot32 on 2017/10/26.

public class AnimationText extends TextView {

private boolean isAnimationStarted;
private float targetLength;
private float totalLength;

private Paint strikePaint;
private float startY;

//should always show Strike-Through
private boolean isDeleted;

public AnimationText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    strikePaint = new Paint();
    strikePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    strikePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    strikePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    strikePaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
}

public AnimationText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    strikePaint = new Paint();
    strikePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    strikePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    strikePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    strikePaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (isAnimationStarted) {
        //画线
        canvas.drawLine(0, startY, targetLength, startY, strikePaint);
    }
    if (isDeleted && !isAnimationStarted) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, startY, totalLength, startY, strikePaint);
    }
}

public void startStrikeThroughAnimation() {
    totalLength = getWidth();
    startY = (float) getHeight() / 2;
    isAnimationStarted = true;
    //利用动画逐渐画出一条删除线
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "targetLength", 0, totalLength);
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            isAnimationStarted = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    objectAnimator.setDuration(300);
    objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            invalidate();
        }
    });
    objectAnimator.start();
    postInvalidate();
}

public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
    isDeleted = deleted;
    totalLength = getWidth();
}

public float getTargetLength() {
    return targetLength;
}

public void setTargetLength(float targetLength) {
    this.targetLength = targetLength;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @oferiko answer, strike animation:

```
private static ValueAnimator startStrikeThruAnimation(TextView textView, int duration){

    final SpannableString span = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
    final StrikethroughSpan strikeSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
    final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(textView.getText().length());

    animator.setDuration(duration);
    animator.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
        span.setSpan(strikeSpan, 0, (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(span);
        textView.invalidate();
    });

    animator.start();
    return animator;
}
```

and for reverse animation:

```
private static ValueAnimator reverseStrikeThruAnimation(TextView textView, int duration){

    final CharSequence originalText = textView.getText();
    final Spannable span = new SpannableString(originalText);
    final StrikethroughSpan strikeSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
    final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalText.length(), 0);

    // Remove existing strike-through span if present
    StrikethroughSpan[] existingSpans = span.getSpans(0, span.length(), StrikethroughSpan.class);
    for (StrikethroughSpan existingSpan : existingSpans) {
        span.removeSpan(existingSpan);
    }

    animator.setDuration(duration);
    animator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        int animatedValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        span.setSpan(strikeSpan, 0, animatedValue, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(span);
        textView.invalidate();
    });

    animator.start();
    return animator;
}
```

usage:

```
startStrikeThruAnimation(sampleTextView, 150);
reverseStrikeThruAnimation(nicknameTextView, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have following options:

Extend TextView and make a custom view which checks if the STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG is set and fires off an animation that will draw a small line on the text incrementing it's width on each frame of the animation.

Use an empty view and place it on your TextView (using RelativeLayout, FrameLayout etc). Make sure the dimensions of this view match exactly with your TextView. Then animate this view following the same strategy as before: Draw a horizontal line at the center of the view whose width is incremented at each frame of the animation.